# Load testing results on blitz.io and new relic for the same config show different queuing times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, newrelic, heroku-postgres

i am testing a rails 4.0 app on blitz.io and new relic..

```
Blitz: 200 users, 4000 Timeout, in 60sec.
Heroku: 20 dynos (2x standard dynos).
Database: Postgresql 200 connections plan
Using Unicorn at 7 processes(new relic shows that my app uses about 140mb,
so for a 2x standard dyno, you get 1gb, and so 1024/140 is about 7. link ref for this in below line)
ref: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/2188-how-to-improve-rails-application-performance-on-heroku/
```

For the same config and multiple tests i see response queuing in new relic ranging from 240ms to 443ms. I would like to know why its varying that much. what else should i be monitoring. how can i reduce it to atleast 50ms? also what is the ideal response queuing time?

thanks

Comment: You should provide more details. what does `dynos at 2x` mean? Also, are you using 7 unicorn workers (plus one master) per dyno? That sounds like too much.

Comment: I see. I still think that 7 is too much. The Unicorn master process uses RAM too, hence you should actually use 1 master + 6 workers. However, I strongly suggest to leave some free memory for the occasional spike, and to let Unicorn handle hot-restarts (when it will fork a new master while the old one is still running).

Comment: will do that thanks..